# Rercusive template for processing type of each argument

Tags: templates, c++11, tuples, variadic-templates

This is a generic function for building an object of given type. Thanks to variadics templates If a matching constructor is found T will be constructed, else the compiler will throw an error at compile-time.

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
void * build(Args... args){
    return new T(args...);
}
```

Now assume that instead of passing N parameters, I want to get them from somewhere else, for example from a singleton, then I have to expand in someway the Arguments and call a method based on the type of each argument:

```
class Singleton{

public:
    template <typename T>
    static T* getIstance(){ 
        return reinterpret_cast<T*>(istances_map[typeid(T).has_code()]);
    }
};
```

Now assume that I call

```
MyClass * p = build<MyClass,Foo,Bar>();
```

What I want to do is that MyClass Constructor is called, and corresponding istances of Foo and Bar are get from the singleton. This should be and example of expanded template code:

```
MyClass * p = new MyClass( Singleton::getIstance<Foo>(),
                           Singleton::getIstance<Bar>()  
                          );
```

I have the feeling that i need a recursive template along with a tuple for solve that problem. But that's just a feeling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
T* build()
{
    return new T{Singleton::getInstance<Args>()...};
}
```

Comment: You "mispelled" `getIstance` ;)

Comment: stackoverflow don't let me edit just "1 character" for the mispelling. It was really hard decide wich one vote to be best answer and finally I flipped a coin :/. Sorry for the other guy. But maybe would be nice see also a recursive solution ^^ (if someone want the best answer without randomness in the choice)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
T* build() {
  return new T(Singleton::getIstance<Args>()...);
}
```